# What are some examples of XRP nodes?

Tags: ripple

What are some URLs of XRP nodes that I would be able to query the current transaction fee from, as well as send a raw transaction to? www.developers.ripple.com gives a lot of information on how to interact with a node, but it doesn't give me examples of the node URLs themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the public servers provided by `Ripple Inc`. Though they do not recommend keep on using it in production.

with websockets: `wss://s2.ripple.com:443` ... s2 is the full history node iirc
with json-rpc: `http://s1.ripple.com:51234`

If you want to try it out on the `test network`:

with websockets: `wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233`
with json-rpc: `https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234`

source: [test network faucet](https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/)

Answer (score 1):

The URL https://data.ripple.com worked for me. I found the link on https://developers.ripple.com.

Example:
https://data.ripple.com/v2/transactions/9D591B18EDDD34F0B6CF4223A2940AEA2C3CC778925BABF289E0011CD8FA056E